# How to target a a specific div on a page with the same class as another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, slider

I am creating a basic slider to show products on a page. I will want to use multiple sliders on a page. But obviously when I execute the function, it effects all sliders because they have the same class name. But they need the same class for the css. The sliders will also have different values, e.g. amount of products.

I want to put multiple sliders on a page but the function only effect the slider clicked.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32TU5/)

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
   <div class="slider-controls>
       <div class="prv control"> < </div>
       <div class="nxt control"> > </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider">
      <!-- SLIDE 1--><div class="slide"><img></div>
      <!-- SLIDE 1--><div class="slide"><img></div>
      <!-- SLIDE 1--><div class="slide"><img></div>
      <!-- SLIDE 1--><div class="slide"><img></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.nxt').click(function){
   .slider{move left}
}

    $('.prv').click(function){
   .slider{move right}
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32TU5/)

Comment: store the buttons as variables, they will be for their own for each slider instance

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).closest('.slider-wrapper').find('.slider')....`

Comment: I have put them as variables in the jsfiddle its just that there are calculations made on the slider on click to determine how much the slider has to move each time

Answer (score 0):

You have all kinds of options.

1. Add an *additional* class uniquely identifying each slider (elements can have multiple classes).
2. Use `id`s to unique identify them.
3. Use their *contents* to uniquely identify them (e.g., presumably each `img` is different).
4. Do it positionally, via the [`.eq` function](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

   ```
   var firstSlider = $(".slider").eq(0);
   var secondSlider = $(".slider").eq(1);
   ```

   ...or [`:eq` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

   ```
   var firstSlider = $(".slider:eq(0)");
   var secondSlider = $(".slider:eq(1)");
   ```

   ...or by grabbing all of them and just indexing into the set:

   ```
   var sliders = $(".slider");
   var firstSlider = $(sliders[0]);
   var secondSlider = $(sliders[1]);
   ```
5. When responding to an event on one of the sliders, if you need to know which one it is relative to its siblings, use the [`index` function](http://api.jquery.com/index):

   ```
   $(".sliders").on("some-event", function() {
       // Which slider am I?
       var sliderIndex = $(this).index();
   });
   ```

*(In the above, I'm not literally suggesting using individual variables for the sliders, just using the vars to show which one you'd be getting from each mechanism.)*

Comment: I will be using this in a content management system so sliders will just be added when needed be users so I will not be able to add separate class's to each individual one or know its position, although would it work if i put. $('.nxt').click(function(){var pos = $(this).parent().eq} or something like that

Comment: @navigator: I think your comment got cut off there. If you mean, how do you know which slider you're dealing with within an event handler, by default `this` will be the DOM element on which the event was hooked. (See my example #5 for one possible use of `this` in that regard, but if you just need to use the slider, you don't need `index`, just `this` and [if you need jQuery features] `$(this)`.)

Comment: @navigator: Re your edited comment (which completed the cut-off bit): I think you're looking for #4 above. You may need to limit it some, like `$(".nxt").click(function() { var secondSlider = $(this).closest(".slider-wrapper").find(".slider").eq(1); });`

Comment: How would i declare the variables relative to that specific slider? check http://jsfiddle.net/32TU5

Comment: @navigator: See the comment above, where we find the sliders within the `.slider-wrapper` that the `.nxt` is in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is that yo use class="slide" for all your div. 
Use different ID identifier